# Print from Win98 vm to a printer on host that does not have 98 support

Tags: virtualbox, drivers, virtual-machine, printing

Well I managed to fit the whole question in the title.

My printer does not have Win98 support. Is there a way to print to a printer on the host that does not support windows 98?

I am using virtualbox on a Win XP machine. I can change to any other vm program but Win98 is a must for my task.

Any thoughts or simple workarounds BESIDES .pdf printer? I know how to get files off of the vm. I would just like to be able to press print.

Comment: i assume you tried setting your printer as network printer?

Comment: first method I tried

Comment: setup a file sharing using IP addresses and then just copy and paste your PDF files into there.  Goto non-virtual computer and open and print them.

Comment: That worked for me. And I was also able to get shared clipboard to work as well. So I have plenty of solutions to my problem. If you want to submit your answer so I can accept it cybernard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup a file sharing using IP addresses and then just copy and paste your PDF files into there. Goto non-virtual computer and open and print them.

Comment: File sharing between Windows 10 and 98 can be difficult to setup nowadays. This forum post helped me do it: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=69323

Answer (score 1):

When you choose the printer driver on the 98 VM, if your printer supports it, you just need to select the `Generic / Text Only` driver. This driver just sends the ASCII down the wire + some control codes and lets the printer's internal logic handle the rest.

I don't have a screenshot of it in 98 but the UI for the driver selection screen has not changed much and here is what it looks like in 7.

[image]

---

On my quest for search for a better screenshot [I found a good article](http://www.frogmorecs.com/arts/using-the-generic-driver) explaining how to set up the Text Only driver. (I discovered in the article the manufacture will be `Microsoft` not `Generic` for the driver in windows 98)

Comment: This has worked for me in the past, But the printers we have there would not work with that setup.  I have finally got it working at an acceptable level for my customer. And I am so happy I am done with it. I am very sorry I had to hit you guys with win 98 stuff... (money talks b.s. walks, had to do the job!) Thank you for answer